# How to extract content from delimiters in php

Tags: php, parsing

I'm looking to extract a content in php from delimiters. For example :

```
content useless
<--------->
Content to get
content to get
content to get
<--------->
content useles
content useless
<--------->
Content to get
content to get
content to get
<--------->
content useless
<--------->
Content to get
content to get
content to get
<--------->
```

For now I only have this :

```
<?php
$myfile = file_get_contents("foo.txt");
$rows = explode("\n", $myfile);

foreach($row as $line => $data) {
    if ($data == "<--------->") {

    }
}
?>
```

I don't really know how to find the second position of my delimiter and retrieve the content.

I hope I got myself clear !
Greetings and thanks.

Comment: you want to extract content based on <----------> this delimiter?

Comment: For example yes or something else

Comment: will always be between <--------->? and how many possible blocks?

Comment: Yeah I edited my post, always between <---------> and "infinity" of blocks

Comment: Nope, the two delimiters are just delimiters, not part of the data

Comment: Useful data is simply some strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give get the content of all blocks between  <--------> as delimiter

```
$pattern = '/<-{9}>([\S\s]*?)<-{9}>/';

$subject = "
<--------->
Content to get
content to get
content to get
<--------->
Some extra stuff
<--------->
Content to get
content to get
content to get
<--------->";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);



$allBlocks = $matches[1];


foreach($allBlocks as $block)
{
   var_dump(explode("\n", $block));

}
```

However, you should try to be more structured in defining delimiters.

As the beginning of your content are the same as the end of content. `<--------->` you may be in troubles later when scaling your code or if the content also contain the  `<--------->`

Try implementing some XML tags like `</-------->` Or a custom form.

**##BOU## Stuff \n stuff ##EOU##**

AS BOU /EOU being Beggining/End of usefull stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
<?php
    $g = file_get_contents("foo.txt");
    preg_match('#\<---------\>\r\n(.*?)\r\n\<---------\>#s',$g,$matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

will give output:

```
Content to get
content to get
content to get
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It looks like it's not working for me :/

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// $sections will be an array with elements that contains rows between <---->
$sections = explode(PHP_EOL.'<--------->'.PHP_EOL, file_get_contents("foo.txt"));
?>
```

Now you can iterrate over sections and again explode by PHP_EOL, then you will get array where each element is a row of file.

You can change PHP_EOL for "\r" or "\n" if you need it.

edit:

```
<?php

    $sections = explode(PHP_EOL.'<--------->'.PHP_EOL, file_get_contents("foo.txt"));

    //  each section contains file content between <---------> and next <---------> (additionaly start of file when it does not starts with <---------> 
    foreach ($sections as $section){

        $rows   =   explode(PHP_EOL, $section);

        foreach($rows as $row){

            //  display section row
            echo $row.'<br />';

        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: You mean I should replace the foreach by your solution ?

Comment: @Maytyn Your code will still give you the `content useless` part as `explode()` will break on the delimiter, and not extract content between the delimiter.

Comment: file_get_contents("foo.txt") returns you a file content as string. Each row is separated by new line new line by default is PHP_EOL. By exploding array by new line + <-----> + new line you receive array where each element contains rows between <----> <---->. now you can iterrate over array element to get separate row.

Comment: Cause when I use your code, it just get all the file, I think I did something wrong

Comment: Try to replace PHP_EOL with "\r" or "\n"

Comment: @NiketMalik Yeah, right, but if there's only 1 delimeter content will be always $sections[1]